# How to segregate data into groups based on the value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the below format:

| Pan_no | ANA_Code | R_units | R_price | absolute_returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BBJ | Equity | 1.5 | 500 | 15000 |
| AAX | Debt | 2.0 | 1500 | 3000 |
| EDF | Debt | 3.0 | 500 | -91 |

Like the above sample data i have 10,000,000 records available. Now I require another column were i need to divide absolute_returns columns into bins(groups) and put them into 5 buckets based on the values like 1,2,3,4,5 then i need to find sum(r_price),sum(r_units) which is then grouped by pan_no, ana_code, and bins(this bins is the new column that will be created).

I tried to achieve the above with the below code:

```sql
select 
    pan_no, ana_code, 
    sum(r_units), sum(r_price),
    ntile(5) over (order by absolute_returns) as bins 
from 
    table1 
group by 
    pan_no, ana_code, bins;
```

What am I missing in my code? I am just trying to create 5 bins for absolute_returns column and then summing up the r_price and r_units and then trying to group the data by pan_no, ana_code and bins. But the code doesn't work.

Comment: Expected results would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using SQL server;

```
select 
    pan_no, ana_code, 
    sum(r_units), sum(r_price),
    ntile(5) OVER(PARTITION BY pan_no,ana_code, ORDER BY absolute_returns ASC) as bins
from 
    table1 
group by 
    pan_no, ana_code;
```

Change asc to desc if needed.